# Copying pages doesn't work (SPO)

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, copy-content

Another day with SharePoint, another issues. :)
I need to copy pages within one site, (from the top site to a subsite).
Of course, there is no out of the box functionality for this, therefore I need to get creative. ;)
I created an instant flow, it runs without a problem, no errors - the page seems to have copied. But once I open it, I am getting the error:

> Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred.

How do I go about it?

---

**Update from comments**:

Here is the flow I am using currently:

[image]

**Note**: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use PowerShell commands.

Comment: Can you show us how you have configured your flow to copy page from site to subsite?

Comment: In case you want to achieve using PowerShell + PnP. there are two command that you can use. `Get-PnPFile` -> to download the page locally. Then `Add-PnPFile` -> To upload the page.

Comment: I usually use these commands to copy pages from one site collection to another / or from one library to another. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed the same task in SharePoint Online using the below steps.  Note: Your account has to be in the Owners group with Full Control on the destination site (your subsite) for the copy operation to successfully complete.

1. Go to the **Site Pages** library.
2. Click **Return to Classic SharePoint**.
3. Click the **File** tab in the ribbon. Select the checkbox of the page to copy. Click **Send to** and then select **Copy**.
4. Enter the link of the destination site’s **Site Pages** library. Rename the page (optional). Click **Ok**.
5. In the Copy dialog, click **Ok**.
6. Close the Copy dialog box.
7. The copied file will appear in the target library.

For screenshots and additional information [read this](https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2022/09/22/copy-site-page-to-another-site-without-power-automate/).